# Automating nonsignificant term removal from linear models

Tags: r, lm, anova

Im working on a data set that includes categorical and continuous independent variables and want to find out what the minimum adequate model is.

This is the starting model:

```
mod1 <- lm(Richness ~ Distances*Flower*Veg*Canopy*factor(Vines), data = Data)
anova(mod1)
```

I am then removing nonsignificant interaction terms and variables by a manual process like so:

```
mod2 <- update(mod1, ~.-Canopy:factor(Vines))
anova(mod2)
```

Is there a way of automating this process?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There's actually a really useful discussion of model selection in the ISLR Videos. Even better, the last 4 videos provide practical examples using R: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5-da3qGB5IB-Xdpj_uXJpLGiRfv9UVXI

Comment: Yes! `step` was exactly what I was looking for thank you @nongkrog.

Comment: @nongkrong, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker I think I found a solution through nongkrong's suggestion, and have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following what @nongkrong suggested about the `step` function I think I found a solution:

```
model.null = lm(Abundance ~ 1,
            data=data) #define the null model#
model.full = lm(Abundance ~ Distances*Flower*Veg*Canopy*factor(Vines), 
            data = data) #define the max model#

step(model.full, #start at the full model#
 scope = list(lower = model.null), # the lower limit of model it can produce#
 direction = "backward", #work by deleting terms until you get to the minimum model #
 data = data
)
```

It seems to work so far, if anyone sees a problem with this code please comment.